# Django Channels group send doesn't send any data to the group

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, django-redis

My websocket works, but doesn't send any data to the group

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    # admin interface
    'jet',
    # django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 3rd party
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'rest_framework',
    'multiselectfield',
    'django_celery_results',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'channels',
    # my apps
    "ads",
    "authentication",
]

# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gozle_ads.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'gozle_ads.asgi.application'


CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
    },
}


# consumers.py

import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer


class BannerConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        
        self.room_name = "banner_changer"
        self.room_group_name = "banner_changer_group"

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_name, self.room_group_name
        )
        self.send(json.dumps({"messgae": "Connected to the banner websocket"}))

    def receive(self, text_data=None):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "banner_changer_group",
            {
                "type": "banner_ads_socket",
                "value": f"{text_data}"
            }
        )
    
    def disconnect(self, code):
        print("DISCONNECTED")

    def banner_ads_socket(self, event):
        print("BANNER ADS")
        print(event)


# asgi.py

import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import re_path

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

from ads.consumers import BannerConsumer

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gozle_ads.settings')

ws_patterns = [
    re_path(r"ws/banner/", BannerConsumer.as_asgi())
]


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": URLRouter(ws_patterns),
})
```

when I'm sending data to the `receive` method nothing is happening, method `banner_ads_socket` doesn't work. It doesn't raise any errors. First, I'm adding consumer to my group, then sending data to the group. I copied that from video. In the this code works, but my code not. What can I do with that?